# Why need mapping to slots to embed bytes in AES-homomorphic encryption?

Tags: aes, homomorphic-encryption

The encoding of each AES bytes $_$ is using CRT(Chinese remainder theorem). It means that there is an aggregate plaintext $H$ such that:

- $H \mod F_0 =_0(MappingData[0])$
- $H \mod F_1 =_1(MappingData[1])$

  ...
- $H \mod F_{15} =_{15}(MappingData[15])$

It uses the $MappingData$ to map between $GF(2^8)$ representation and representation relative to the slot polynomials $GF(2^{16})$ (or bigger).
Since each $_$ is an element of $GF(2^8)$, embedded into a slot of bigger $GF(2^{16})$, why do we need to map them instead of just putting them into the slots?

Furthermore, if there is a mapping $H(X) \rightarrow H(X^i)$ and the elements in the slots rotate, will the position of $MappingData[i]$ inside a byte $_j$ unchanged?

Like

- $H \mod F_0 =_5(MappingData[0])$
- $H \mod F_1 =_6(MappingData[1])$

  ...
- $H \mod F_{15} =_4(MappingData[15])$

Comment: "The encoding of each AES bytes $\alpha_i$ is using CRT". Where?  Are you talking about this paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/099  ?

Comment: Yes, I do. :) And also the detaisl in  https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/566 and https://people.csail.mit.edu/shaih/pubs/he-library.pdf .

Comment: this MappingData structure is only present on the last paper you linked and it doesn't seem that it is multiplied by the polynomials stored in each slot.... Where did you find those expressions $\alpha_i (MappingData[i] )$ ?

Comment: Actually, I also reference the implementation source code released by the author here https://github.com/shaih/HElib/blob/master/src/PAlgebra.cpp in line 538, the method embedInSlots(). But I thought it's like a math question rather than a coding question, therefore I just type them here, sorry for not posting it up. The presentation of MappingData[i] here is not a multiplication, it is a **CompondMod**. If **g** is a polynomial and **h** is also a polynomial, **CompondMod** means substituting h into g with both coefficient mod 2, like g(h).